# I'm having issues using the credential manager through chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to integrate the credential manager API into my extension so I can save the API credentials using it but am having issues.
Just for testing purposes, I just tried saving the credentials from the popup (Where the user login happens) and when I tried that I got an error saying "NotSupportedError: The user agent does not support public key credentials." I did some googling but didn't find what I was looking for. I thought it might have something to do with the popup so I tried doing the same through the background script but it can't access the window object so that didn't work.
I haven't yet tried doing this though a content script which I would imagine would work but ideally I'd prefer to just store it when the user logs in and then just call it as I need it.
Here is the basic code I'm using for testing that I grabbed from the MDN site;

```
                        if ("PasswordCredential" in window) {
                            let cmAPICredential = new PasswordCredential({
                            id: "extension",
                            name: uname, 
                            password: pwd
                            });
                        
                            navigator.credentials.store(cmAPICredential).then(() => {
                                if (isDebugMode) {
                                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "debug_log", str: `**LOGIN DEBUGGING** | Credentials stored in the user agent's credential manager.`, cpage: "main.js" }, function(response) {});
                                }
                            }, (err) => {
                            if (isDebugMode) {
                                    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "debug_log", str: `**LOGIN DEBUGGING** | Error while storing the credential: ${err}`, cpage: "main.js" }, function(response) {});
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            if (isDebugMode) {
                                chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ message: "debug_log", str: `**LOGIN DEBUGGING** | Password credential isn't supported in this browser`, cpage: "main.js" }, function(response) {});
                            }
                        }
Is there any way that I can do what I am attempting? The only thing I really want to secure is the password and this seems to be the only good way to do it through a chrome extension.
```

Comment: Edit:  I've confirmed that I can access the API fine through a content script but that doesn't really help since the user login happens on the popup so I'd still need to store the password somewhere until the content script would run to then store into the CM.

Comment: Another edit: On doing more research I don't know if this will in fact, work or not. Since the credential data can only be accessed on the original domain, unless the chrome extension ID would be used as the domain, I wonder if I'd be able to access the credential data as if the user saved credentials for a website that was using the extension, when I called get(), would I get the website credentials or the extension credentials.

Comment: Extensions aren't supported by the credentials API.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @wOxxOm response and some other research, it looks like I can't use the credential management API with chrome extensions.
So the answer to my question is you can't.